# Pattern for Induction?

Tags: summation, induction

> Find and prove a formula for the sum 
>   $$\frac{1^3}{1^4+4} - \frac{3^3}{3^4+4}+...+\frac{(-1)^n(2n+1)^3}{(2n+1)^4 + 4}$$ where $n$ is an integer.

I tried listing out the partial sums of the sequence to see if there was a pattern, however the only thing I can make out is that the denominators of the sum always either end in 5 or 9.

I would just like a hint as to how to solve this.
Thanks.

Comment: It seems like it might be useful to use that $x^4+4=(x^2-2x+2)(x^2+2x+2)$ so you might be able to a telescoping sum of some sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extended hint:

Writing down 4-5 first partial sums reveals after reducing the fractions the general pattern:
$$
S_n=(-1)^n\frac{n+1}{4(n+1)^2+1}.
$$
It remains to apply induction or telescoping. The following facts will be useful:
$$\begin{array}{ll}
(2n+1)^4+4&=(4n^2+1)(4n^2+8n+5),\\
4n^2+8n+5&=4(n+1)^2+1,\\
(2n+1)^3-n(4n^2+8n+1)&=(n+1)(4n^2+1). 
\end{array}
$$

> $\frac{(2n+1)^3}{(2n+1)^4+4}=\frac{n}{4n^2+1\vphantom{)^2}}+\frac{n+1}{4(n+1)^2+1}.$

Comment: When I factor the denominator (in an attempt to get the general pattern above), I get $(4(n+1)^2+1)(4n^2+1)$. However, the numerator $(2n+1)^3 = (n+1)(4n^2+1) + n(4n^2 + 8n + 1)$ like you said above. It seems as if the $(4n^2+1)$ term should cancel, but it doesn't.

Comment: It cancels. You should demonstrate $$\frac{(2n+1)^3}{(2n+1)^4+4}-\frac{n}{4n^2+1}=\frac{n+1}{4(n+1)^2+1}.$$

Comment: Ah, I understand. Thank you.